# Derived Completion

Tags: limits, algebraic-geometry, derived-categories

I am reading Lecture III of Bhatt, Bhargav. Geometric aspects of prismatic cohomology. Fall 2018.

Let $A$ be a commutative ring, $f\in A$ and $M$ an $A$-module. The module can be seen as a complex $M\in D(A)$ with $M$ sitting in degree zero and zeroes elsewhere.

The derived $f$-adic completion $\hat M\in D(A)$ of $M\in D(A)$ is defined as $R\lim_n(M\otimes^L_{\mathbb{Z}[x]}\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^n)$ where $x$ acts by $f$.

There is a standard resolution of \[(\mathbb{Z}[x]\to \mathbb{Z}[x])\to \mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^n),\]where the first map is multiplication with $x^n$ that helps compute the derived tensor product in the definition of $\hat M$.

Explicitly, $M\otimes^L_{\mathbb{Z}[x]}\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^n)\cong (\cdots \to 0 \to  M \to M \to 0 \to  \cdots)$
sitting in degrees $-1$ and $0$, where the non-trivial map is multiplication by $f^n$. We can denote this inverse system by $(K_n,f^n)$ and with this notation we get a distinguished triangle \[K\to \prod K_n \to \prod K_n \to K[1]\]where $K=\hat M$ and  $(k_n)\mapsto (k_n-f^{n+1}k_{n+1})$ is the map between the products.

This distinguished triangle induces a long exact sequence of cohomology groups \[\cdots \to H^{i-1}(\prod K_n) \to H^i(K) \to  H^i(\prod K_n) \to H^i(\prod K_n) \to H^{i+1}(K) \to  \cdots\]

The author now says that $H^{-1}(K)=\lim_{n}M[f^n]$ and that the zeroeth cohomology group sits in a short exact sequence \[0\to R^1\lim M[f^n]\to H^0(K)\to \lim M/f^nM\to 0\]

But I do not see either of these statements. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to write out the definition for the derived inverse limit involving the product above. Instead, you can argue as follows:

As you observed above, the derived tensor product $M/^L(f^n):=M\otimes^{L}_{\mathbb{Z}[x]}\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^n)$ can be calculated using the resolution $\mathbb{Z}[x]\xrightarrow{x^n} \mathbb{Z}[x].$
We find that $H^{-1}(M/^L(f^n))=M[f^n]$ and that $H^0(M/^L(f^n))=M/(f^n)$, and that all the other cohomology groups are zero.
Therefore, we have the following distinguished triangle in the derived category:
$$ M[f^n][1]\to M/^L(f^n)\to M/(f^n)\xrightarrow{[1]}.$$
Taking the derived inverse limit, we have the following long exact sequence in the category of abelian groups:
$$0\to R^{-1}lim(M[f^n][1])\to R^{-1}lim(M/^L(f^n))\to R^{-1}lim(M/(f^n))\to R^0lim(M[f^n][1])\to R^0lim(M/^L(f^n))\to R^0lim(M/(f^n))\to 0.$$
Using that the derived limit of countable system of abelian groups vanishes outside of cohomological degree 0 and 1, we have that the middle term $R^{-1}lim(M/(f^n))=0$.
Therefore, the above long exact sequence gives rise to the isomorphism:
$$R^0lim(M[f^n])\cong H^{-1}(\hat{M}),$$
and the short exact sequence
$$0\to R^1lim(M[f^n])\to H^0(\hat{M})\to R^0lim(M/(f^n))\to 0,$$
which are exactly what you want.